# Stripe Payment Gateway return error

Tags: expresso-store

I'm trying to process a payment with Stripe, but am getting an error after the form submits and reloads.  The error is

"Sorry, there was an unexpected error communicating with the payment gateway."

I did a little digging and dumped out the exception being throw inside OrdersService.php file. The exception message says "The number parameter is required"

Any thoughts what the issue may be?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Here is the code

Checkout Page: https://gist.github.com/bryantAXS/6989698

JS: https://gist.github.com/bryantAXS/6989724 (Token created at line 315)

I can confirm the token is being created and added to the payment[token] field correctly before the page has submitted.

UPDATE 2: I've written a new answer below that is a temporary fix until more clarification or the source is updated.

Comment: Can you post the template code for the final page along with the JS you are using to create a stripe token?

Comment: I am getting the same, so looking forward to seeing how this works out

Comment: It seems like the issue has to do with Store trying to validate a credit card. The "The number parameter is required" is coming from CreditCard.php where it validates a credit card. -- The bigger issue is why is it validating a credit card number when the stripe token is supposed to take the place of one.

Comment: Stripe still validates the CC details locally before sending the details over to be processed. There were a few things that you need to change in your template. I am posting an answer below.

Comment: I have been seeing that error as well and using the latest source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've somewhat pinpointed the issue, but I'm not too sure where to start fixing it.

Essentially, the token generated on the client side which is being set to an input with the name payment[token] is not being recognized inside the payment processing.

Inside the file `Omnipay/Stripe/Message/AuthorizeRequest.php` file there is a if/else conditional looking for the token, however that token wasn't being found.

inside the getToken() method being called to retrieve it (line 153 of Common/Message/AbstractRequest.php) , there was the line

`return $this->getParameter('token');`

I replaced that with

`return $_POST["payment"]["token"]`
And the checkout processed correctly.

Naming the form payment[token] is how the documentation says to set it, but there seems to be a bug somewhere there.

Comment: Thanks for tracking this down - you are correct, it does look like a bug and we will have a fix out very shortly!

Comment: Has this now been fixed? We're running store 2.0.6 and we're still getting a "The number parameter is required" for unknown reasons.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here - this code is the same as of V2.06

Comment: This specific should have been fixed, but you can get the same error if your not setting your token correctly in your form.

Answer (score 2):

Store 2.x use the new Stripe.js which requires that you use `data-stripe=""` on your form elements oppose to `id=""` and `name=""`for all of your payment specific fields. Here is a stripped down version of your template:

```
<h4>Payment Information</h4>

<label>Name</label>
<input data-stripe="name" type="text" placeholder="">

<label>Credit Card Number</label>
<input data-stripe="number" type="text" placeholder="">

<label>Expiration Month</label>
<div class="select-wrapper">
<span class="select-text">January</span>
<span class="ss-dropdown"></span>
<select data-stripe="exp-month" id="payment_exp_month" class="hidden-dropdown">
  <option value="01" data-text="January">January</option>
  <option value="02" data-text="February">February</option>
  <option value="03" data-text="March">March</option>
  <option value="04" data-text="April">April</option>
  <option value="05" data-text="May">May</option>
  <option value="06" data-text="June">June</option>
  <option value="07" data-text="July">July</option>
  <option value="08" data-text="August">August</option>
  <option value="09" data-text="September">September</option>
  <option value="10" data-text="October">October</option>
  <option value="11" data-text="November">November</option>
  <option value="12" data-text="December">December</option>
</select>
</div>

<label>Expiration Year</label>
<div class="select-wrapper">
<span class="select-text">2013</span>
<span class="ss-dropdown"></span>
<select data-stripe="exp-year" id="payment_exp_year" class="hidden-dropdown">
  <option value="2013" data-text="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2014" data-text="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015" data-text="2015">2015</option>
  <option value="2016" data-text="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2017" data-text="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2018" data-text="2018">2018</option>
  <option value="2019" data-text="2019">2019</option>
  <option value="2020" data-text="2020">2020</option>
</select>
</div>

<label>Card Verification Number</label>
<input data-stripe="cvc" type="text" placeholder="">

<input type="hidden" id="payment_token" name="payment[token]" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="payment_method" value="stripe">
```

Once you do that you will need to update your JS to use the new store.js. In its most basic form you will need the following:

```
$(function() {
    $.getScript('https://js.stripe.com/v2/', function() {
        Stripe.setPublishableKey('YOUR_PUBLISHABLE_KEY_HERE');
    });

    /* Ensure your checkout submit button has id="checkout_submit" */
    $checkout_submit = $("#checkout_submit").click(function() {

        /* Only handle requests for Stripe gateway */
        if (this.form.elements["payment_method"].value == "stripe") {

            /* Temporarily disable the checkout submit button */
            $checkout_submit.attr('disabled', true);

            /* Create a Stripe card token */
            Stripe.card.createToken($(this.form), stripeResponseHandler);

            /* We don't want to submit the form yet */
            return false;
        }
    });

    /* This function is triggered once Stripe has generated the token */
    function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
        /* Re-enable the checkout submit button */
        $checkout_submit.attr('disabled', false);

        /* Check whether we have a valid credit card */
        if (response.error) {
            alert(response.error.message);
        } else {
            /* Set the card token and submit the checkout form */
            $("#payment_token").val(response.id);
            $checkout_submit.off("click").click();
        }
    }
});
```

Once you have that working you can use the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms) to add any additional functionality that you want.

- [Adjusted Checkout Template](https://gist.github.com/therealjustinlong/6994416)

Comment: Wow - thanks for the answer Justin, however I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in [Store 2.0.4](https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html#store_204):

> Fixed an error with Stripe gateway where card token was not submitted correctly

Per Bryant's answer, in Store 2.0.3 the card token was not being correctly passed through to Stripe which meant the payment was unsuccessful.

Comment: This is still happening for me in stripe 2.0.4. I made the change above to the file and it allowed the form to send, but when run off a vanilla 2.0.4 I get the same result.

Comment: Aaron did you get your issue sorted? It sounds like your problem wasn't to do with Stripe at all.

Comment: yeah for some reason the local server would say that store was updated, but the files weren't in fact overwritten. Some sort of permissions errors on the copy-over. - cheers